# $a\sqrt{a}+b\sqrt{b}+c\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{a+b+c}\ge a\left(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)+b\left(\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{a}\right)+c\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\right)$

Tags: inequality

Let: $a,b,c \geq 0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+1=2(ab+bc+ca)$. Prove that:
$$a\sqrt{a}+b\sqrt{b}+c\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{a+b+c}\ge a\left(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)+b\left(\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{a}\right)+c\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\right)$$

Here are my try: Put: $\sqrt{a}=x, \sqrt{b}=y, \sqrt{c}=z$

Then put: $p=x+y+z, q=xy+yz+zx, r= xyz$

So the condition became: $$r= -\frac{1+p^4-2p^2q}{8p}$$

And the inequality became:
$$ p^3 - 3(pq-r) + \sqrt{p^2-2q} \geq pq-3r$$

And I got stuck here!

Answer (score 1):

it's wrong. Try $a=6$ and $b=0.9.$

Comment: My teacher have a proof for it, can you show me the mistake here?

Comment: $\sqrt{[\sum (b+c-a)][\sum a(b+c-a)]} \geq \sum \sqrt{a}(b+c-a)$

Comment: @Lục Trường Phát This C-S works, when $a$, $b$ and $c$ are sides-lengths of some triangle. But for positive variables it's wrong.